# Extract the id from long file path ( regex) perl

Tags: regex, perl, filepath

I am trying to extract an id ( here eg 11894373690) from a file path that i read int my perl script -

```
/my/local/projects/Samplename/analysis/test/output/tool1/11894373690_cast/A1/A1a/
```

and I will further use it create a new path like

```
/my/local/projects/Samplename/analysis/test/output/tool2/11894373690_NEW/
```

I am not able to extract just the id from the path, can anyone please suggest an easy method in perl. I should definitely start learning regular expressions! 
Thanks. 
I am able to get only the last directory name

```
$file = "/my/local/projects/Samplename/analysis/test/output/tool1/11894373690_cast/A1/A1a/ ";

my ($id) = $file =~ /\.(A1[^]+)/i;
```

Update - Sorry all I misspelled "not" as "now" earlier! I am not able to extract the id. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? How did you extract the ID? With a regex? Without it?

Comment: depends on your id. Is it all numerical digits? Always followed by underscore?

Comment: You could try an online regex parser to build it as you go http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html

Comment: If you want to do it in bash using sed, ... **echo "/my/local/projects/Samplename/analysis/test/output/tool1/11894373690_cast/A1/A1a/" | sed -e 's|^.*/\([0-9][0-9]*\)_cast/.*$|\1|'**

Comment: @yonyon100 I am not able to get the id, sorry I misspelled "not" with now in the question earlier and this changes the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex or split are fine, but there are multiple core packages for working with paths.

This uses [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) to split the path and to later join the new one. Note that there is no escaping or such, no `/` counting -- in fact no need to even mention the separator.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use File::Spec::Functions qw(splitdir catdir);

my $path_orig = '...';

my @path = splitdir $path_orig;

my ($mark, $dir);
foreach my $i (0..$#path) 
{ 
    if ($path[$i] =~ m/(\d+)_cast/) 
    {
        $dir = $1;
        $mark = $i;
        last;
    }
}

my $path_new = catdir @path[0..$mark-1], $dir . '_NEW';
```

You can manipulate the `@path` array in other ways, of course -- peel components off of the back of it (`pop @path while $path[-1] !~ /.../`), or iterate and copy into a new array, etc.

The code above is simple and doesn't need extra data copy nor multiple regex matches.

---

Apparently the old and new path have another difference (`tool1` vs `tool2`), please adjust.  The main point is that once the path is split it is simple to go through the array.

As for a simple regex to fetch the id

```
my ($id) = $path =~ m{/(\d+)_cast/};
```

If `\d+_cast` is *certain* to be un-ambiguous (only one dir with that in its name) drop the `/` above.

Answer (score 1):

What so you need to be fixed? and what will be dynamic? for this url, supposing that the posfix will aways be _cast you can use the expression:

```
(\d+)_cast
```

so the ID will be in the first selection group

Comment: Or just `\d+(?=_cast)` and the entire match is the id

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to get the id - it may not be efficient but works for now 
I did

```
my $dir_path = "/my/local/projects/Samplename/analysis/test/output/tool1/11894373690_cast/A1/A1a/ ";
my @keys =(split(/[\/_]+/,$dir_path));
print "Key is $keys3[9]\n";
```

it prints out 11894373690
Thanks all for the suggestions!